# The use of a comma, bracket or nothing?

Tags: commas, parentheses

Firstly, as far as I am aware, 'unjustifiability' is not an actual English word. However, is it ok to use it within the contexts of a philosophy essay?
The The Stanford Encyclopaedia of Philosophy on a topic called 'Contactualism' uses it frequently to explain what it is for something to  be 'wrong.'

Secondly, Which is correct?

As previously stated, what establishes whether something is wrong (for Scanlon) is its unjustifiability

As previously stated, what establishes whether something is wrong for Scanlon is its unjustifiability.

As previously stated, what establishes whether something is wrong, for Scanlon, is its unjustifiability.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean it's not an actual English word? It is clearly a word, it is clearly actual, and it is clearly English. And you yourself even found it used in an encyclopaedia. How can a word possibly get more actual? I am confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, how foolish of me! I just comes up as red and underlined whenever I type it. It comes up as red and underlined on here! I thought it was just a word used in the context of that particular philosophy and wasn't really every day language.@RegDwigнt

Answer (score 1):

Among your choices are

> ... is, for Scanlon, its unjustifiability

or

> .... what establishes, for Scanlon, whether something is wrong ...

I'd use the former if the term "unjustifiability" is a term Scanlon uses frequently, and you are going on to discuss the term.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and last choices are equivalent, as in both cases the punctuation sets off the same parenthetical expression. All three are essentially the same, but I personally wouldn't use any of them, on account of the parenthetical, "for Scanlon", could be mis-interpreted as an prepositional phrase, where Scanlon is identified as the object of what is wrong, rather than the author receiving attribution. I would personally use "according to Scanlon".

Answer (score 0):

There are many places you might put *for Scanlon*, and this is the worst! :) As brasshat says, *wrong for Scanlon* is ambiguous.

Bracketing with commas or parentheses helps, but it's still clunky. Put it somewhere—*anywhere*—else:

> For Scanlon, as previously stated, what establishes whether something is wrong is its unjustifiability.
>   As previously stated, for Scanlon what establishes whether something is wrong is its unjustifiability.
>   As previously stated, what for Scanlon establishes whether something is wrong is its unjustifiability.
>   As previously stated, what establishes for Scanlon whether something is wrong is its unjustifiability.
>   As previously stated, what establishes whether something is wrong is, for Scanlon, its unjustifiability.